# Fortran MOD and MODULO giving same results

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

Compiling with `gfortran --version` == GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 8.2.0) 8.2.0

When I write the following test code I get the functions `MOD` and `MODULO` giving the same results. However, as I understand it from several sources, `MOD` is supposed to give the remainder, and `MODULO` is supposed to give the integer quotient.

```
program test
    implicit none

    print *, mod(17,3)
    print *, mod(17.5,5.5)
    print *, mod(17.5d0,5.5)
    print *, mod(17.5,5.5d0)

    print *, modulo(17,3)
    print *, modulo(17.5,5.5)
    print *, modulo(17.5d0,5.5)
    print *, modulo(17.5,5.5d0)
end program test
```

Prints out:

`2`

`1.00000000`

`1.0000000000000000`

`1.0000000000000000`

`2`

`1.00000000`

`1.0000000000000000`

`1.0000000000000000`

The results are all the remainders, which is what `MOD` is supposed to do, but for `MODULO` isn't it supposed to print out the modulus, in this case `5` and then three `3`'s to varying precision?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might be misunderstanding the purpose of these functions. They are supposed to give you the same answer, namely the remainder after division, when both arguments are positive. But consider the situation with negative arguments:

```
print *, mod( 17,  3)
print *, mod( 17., 3.)
print *, mod(-17,  3)
print *, mod(-17., 3.)
print *, modulo(-17,  3)
print *, modulo(-17., 3.)
```

which will return

```
2
2.000000
-2
-2.000000
1
1.000000
```

so the result of `MODULO(A,P)` will be positive for positive `P` and in fact must have the same sign as `P`. `MODULO` works differently depending on whether `A` and `P` are integers or real numbers. See the documentation for the exact definitions

[MOD](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MOD.html)
[MODULO](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MODULO.html)